# Button doesn`t look like a bootstrap btn-default

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

In this code the link button  doesn't look like a `btn-default` but it is a `btn-default`

```html
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Clases</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Despachos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Otras dependencias</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Extras</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Editor</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Administacion de usuario</a></li>
                <li>
                    <p class="navbar-btn">
                        <a href="#" class='btn btn-default'>Cerrar sesión</a>
                     </p>
                </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: What does CSS have to do with PHP?

Comment: Could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle or so..

Comment: why not you do like this `<a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/user_admin/logout');?>" class="btn btn-default">Cerrar sesión</a>`

Comment: same problem on this way

Comment: @AFS by the way I run your code in sql fiddle and jsfiddle in both i don't see the problem with button (HTML and CSS) why not at-least put a screenshot how the button looks like which you think it shouldn't look like

Comment: Your code snippet is fine. The problem is elsewhere. You probably forgot to include the Bootstrap CSS.

Answer (score 2):

For more info, check this [Bootstrap Button - W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_buttons.asp) or [Bootstrap Button Example - W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_button_elements&stacked=h)
To make anchor tag work as button, you have to **specify role='button'.**

For Ex:

```
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Link Button</a>
```

Add `role='button'` to anchor tag.

```
<?php echo "<a href='".base_url('index.php/user_admin/logout') ."' class='btn btn-default' role='button'>Cerrar sesión</a>"; ?>
```

Comment: it looks in the same way